# Message in visual studio "This extension is scheduled for install"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I have downloaded RDLC extension from visual studio 2017 Tools -> "Extensions & Updates" successfully & its showing me message as

> "This extension is scheduled for install".

So I have restarted my VS2017 (VS Professional 2017 version 15.8.6 ) but still its showing same message & it seems RDLC extension is still not added in VS2017.

I also closed VS using both menu and the close window button (X) in VS but still no luck.

[image: Extension Message]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution. There was another VS instance was running.

I closed all my running VS instances & then "VSIX Installer" installed all my extension.

[image]

Comment: Actually, there are two normal ways to install extensions. Download vsix from MarketPlace or using 'Extensions and Updates' in VS. The latter way won't run the install until all vs instance stop. And if you manually install by .vsix, it will show a 'end task' option to help kill all related process.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for sharing your update. You can mark it as answer to make it easier to be found.

Answer (score 9):

Try, **File -> Close** instead closing VS by clicking **X**

Or else, restarting the PC should work according to the warning shown in the window
Or else, You can change your settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Even though you close your visual studio instances, there may be another instance running in background. So make sure you closed all instances in **Task manager -> Details**.
In my case it started to install once i closed all instances.

Answer (score 1):

If you have opened **visual studio account window** in browser close it & also close your VS. After it VSIX installer will install the extension for you.

Answer (score 1):

Once you close the VS, you should have VSIX installer which will be executed to download and install extension.

Answer (score 0):

For me I restarted my PC/VM and then installed the extension from Visual Studio again. Then I have closed the extension window. Again opened the extension window. And then closed extension window and Visual Studio. Then after couple of seconds a "VSIX installer" window appeared an started to install the extension automatically.